# How to shorten eloquent query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Follow is my query which is working perfectly fine, it is giving me the expected result, but i am not happy with the way i have broken down the query in 3 pieces.
How can i combine this query like without breaking it down in pieces ?

```
$assignedMenusQuery = Branch::with(['menus' => function($query) {
                $query->where('menus.status', true);
            }])
            ->where('id', $branch->id)
            ->first();
            if($assignedMenusQuery)
            {
                $assignedMenus = $assignedMenusQuery->menus->pluck('id')->toArray();
            }

$assignedButSharedMenusQuery = Branch::with(['menus' => function($query) {
                $query->where('menus.shared', true)
                      ->where('menus.status', true);
            }])
            ->whereNotIn('id', [$branch->id])
            ->first();
            if($assignedButSharedMenusQuery)
            {
                $assignedButSharedMenus = $assignedButSharedMenusQuery->menus->pluck('id')->toArray();
            }

$assignedButNotSharedMenusQuery = Branch::with(['menus' => function($query) {
                $query->where('menus.shared', false)
                    ->where('menus.status', true);
            }])
            ->whereNotIn('id', [$branch->id])
            ->first();
            if($assignedButNotSharedMenusQuery)
            {
                $assignedButNotSharedMenus = $assignedButNotSharedMenusQuery->menus->pluck('id')->toArray();
            }

$menus = Menu::whereIn('id', array_merge($assignedMenus, $assignedButSharedMenus))->whereNotIn('id', $assignedButNotSharedMenus)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here what you can do this make a seperate function which accepts a parameter for `shared` & `status`. And other param for `whereNotIn`. And in that function you can use the `when` method and based on that you have to query in database.

[Laravel Conditional Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i did it, in case if someone needs it in future

```
$products = Product::whereNotIn('id', function($query) use($menu) {
                $query->from('menu_product')
                    ->select('menu_product.product_id');
            })
            ->orWhereIn('id', function($query) {
                $query->from('menu_product')
                    ->select('menu_product.product_id')
                    ->where('products.shared', true);
            })
            ->orWhereIn('id', function($query) use($menu) {
                $query->from('menu_product')
                    ->select('menu_product.product_id')
                    ->where('menu_product.menu_id', $menu->id);
            })
            ->get();
```